# How can I extract table with JSOUP

Tags: android, html-table, jsoup, html-parsing

I'm writing an Android app and trying to figure out how should I construct my call to get table data from this webpage: http://uk.soccerway.com/teams/scotland/saint-mirren-fc/1916/squad/

I've read the cookbook from JSOUP website but because I haven't used this library before I am bit stuck. I came up with something like this:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://uk.soccerway.com/teams/scotland/saint-mirrenfc/1916/squad/").get();
Element squad = doc.select("div.squad-container").first(); Element
Elements table = squad.select("table squad sortable");
```

As you can see I'm nowhere near getting players statistics yet. I think the next step should be to point new Element object to "tbody" tag inside the "table squad sortable"? 
I know I will have to use for loop once I manage to read the table and then read each row inside the loop.

Unfortunately table structure is a bit complex for someone with no experience so I would really appreciate some advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically each row has the following selector -
`#page_team_1_block_team_squad_3-table > tbody:nth-child(2) > tr:nth-child(X)` where `X` is the row's number (starting at 1).
One way is to iterate over the rows and extract the info:

```
String url = "http://uk.soccerway.com/teams/scotland/saint-mirren-fc/1916/squad/";
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0";
Document doc = null;
try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
            .userAgent(userAgent)
            .get();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
int i = 1;
Elements row;
do {
    row = doc.select("#page_team_1_block_team_squad_3-table > tbody:nth-hild(2) > tr:nth-child(" + i + ")");
    for (Element el : row) {
        System.out.print(el.select(".shirtnumber").text() + " ");
        System.out.println(el.select(".name").text());
        i++;
    }
} while (row != null);
```

This will print the number and name of each player.  Since I don'r want to count the number of rows (and keep the program felxible for changes), I orefer to use `do...while` loop - I will iterate as ling as the row exists (or not empty).
The output I get:

> 1 J. Langfield
>   21 B. O'Brien
>   28 R. Willison
>   2 S. Demetriou
>   3 G. Irvine
>   4 A. Webster
>   ...

Use your browser's developer tools to get the names of the other columns and use it to get all the info you need.